# Rich text in Lightning design file

Tags: lightning-aura-components, richtextarea, inputrichtext

Hi is there a way to make an attribute in the design file of a Lightning bundle a rich text editor.

The idea is the user to be able to enter rich text which is displayed as a rich text. Also there are translations and the component is used in a public community page that is why I do use my interpretation of translation. And also translation labels do not have rich text editor that is why I am not using them.

Basically I want a to make my custom version of the default Rich Content Editor component.

Design file

```
<design:component >

    <design:attribute name="fiText" label="Rich text in Finish" />
    <design:attribute name="svText" label="Rich text in Svenska" />

</design:component>
```

Cmp file

```
<aura:handler event="c:ChangeLanguageEvent" action="{!c.changeLang}" />

<aura:attribute name="fiText" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="svText" type="String" />

<lightning:formattedRichText value="{! v.lang == 'sv' ? v.svText : v.fiText}" />

</aura:component>
```

Comment: No, you can only use the provided data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is currently not supported. Only String, Integer and Boolean are supported, where Strings can have a datasource that will present as a picklist.

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm